# Activity is in the background, will listener wake it up

Tags: android

If you have two activities A,B that both added connection listener to them. Lets say Activity A started Activity B (so A is in the background onPaused while B is active).

Now connection  event comes, will it execute the code of the listener in both activities or just the visible activity which is B?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. I always register listeners in onResume (after making sure I have the current data) and unregister them in onPause. This way I make sure they only fire in the on-top app. But if you do not do this, the listener methods will be called on the event. Most likely on "A" first because it was registered first as listener.

Sometimes you want to have a listener still listen - maybe you want to finish() both Activities on a disconnect, that's one case where I would not unregister.

So it depends on your usecase.

NOTE: The listener will not "wake it up" in any case. Just the onXXX method will be called.

Comment: Perfect! thats what I was looking for. The unregister on onPause I don't want the onXXX to be called on Activity A